# Cannot SSH into my repositories using SmartSVN

Tags: svn, ssh, smartsvn

I using Windows 8 and have just upgraded from SmartSVN 7.6 to 8.6, having successfully used the 7.6 version for some years both on Windows 7 and 8. I was also able successfully to link to my repos using PuTTY...until I ran the SamrtSVN upgrade to 8.6. Since then I can not longer do so. Whichever way I try, though PuTTY or through SmartSVN, I always get error message saying that the program is unable to connect to the repos.

Here is an extract from SmartSVN log.txt:

```
241304 (2015-07-12 12:18:02,762) [QThreadPoolThread-0 (smartsvn.asa)] ERROR smartsvn.server - There was a problem while connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:22
java.io.IOException: There was a problem while connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:22
at com.trilead.ssh2.Connection.connect(Connection.jav a:817)
at com.trilead.ssh2.Connection.connect(Connection.jav a:686)
at com.syntevo.smartsvn.repository.ssh.i.a(SourceFile :257)
at com.syntevo.smartsvn.repository.ssh.i.a(SourceFile :77)
at com.syntevo.smartsvn.repository.ssh.d.a(SourceFile :146)
at smartsvn.asa.a(SourceFile:24
at smartsvn.vy.run(SourceFile:24)
at smartsvn.vD.run(SourceFile:67)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at com.trilead.ssh2.transport.ClientServerHello.readL ineRN(ClientServerHello.java:31)
at com.trilead.ssh2.transport.ClientServerHello.<init >(ClientServerHello.java:6
at com.trilead.ssh2.transport.TransportManager.initia lize(TransportManager.java:466)
at com.trilead.ssh2.Connection.connect(Connection.jav a:757)
... 7 more
241634 (2015-07-12 12:18:03,092) [QThreadPoolThread-3 (smartsvn.vx)] WARN com.syntevo.svn.remote.SuHlSvnRemoteStatusScanner - Remote status scanner failed for svn+ssh://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/var/svn/xxx
241635 (2015-07-12 12:18:03,093) [QThreadPoolThread-3 (smartsvn.vx)] ERROR smartsvn.remote-state.refresh - Can't create session
svn: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn+ssh://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/var/svn/xxxt/trunk'
Network connection closed unexpectedly
svn: To better debug SSH connection problems, remove the -q option from 'ssh' in the [tunnels] section of your Subversion configuration file.
```

I have uninstalled and re-installed again and again and am now running the SmartSVN portable version of 9, But nothing I do seems to work. I have even tried to re-install 7.6, but now even that cannot connect and no other attempt at an SSH connection by any other means works.

I am able to connect using SmartSVN & PuTTY on my laptop (running a preview version of Windows 10)using the portable version of 9, but nothing I do on my PC seems to help.

I am completely at a loss to know how to fix this issue and cannot even revert to my original pristine 7.6 state. Can anyone help, please?

Comment: please, provide output as it is described in the last line of your code:
`svn: To better debug SSH connection problems, remove the -q option from 'ssh' in the [tunnels] section of your Subversion configuration file.`

Comment: Sorry, but this does nothing different. In fact the line in the config file is commented out anyway...and now I cannot SSH from my laptop any more? Looking at /var/log/auth.log’, this is what I see for the IP address I am using:
Jul 12 07:10:31 B3Me sshd[29351]: refused connect from 192.168.1.4 (192.168.1.4). and WireShark shows the connection terminating with this line 23 0.653606000 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.4 TCP 66 60972→2869 [RST, ACK] Seq=623 Ack=127 Win=5888 Len=0 TSval=28212416 TSecr=2384079.